# How to switch the RN4871 / RN4870 Bluetoothmodul into command mode?

Tags: bluetooth

I try to switch the RN4871 modul into command mode. My actual code ist something like:

```
printf("$");
delay_100ms();
printf("$$\n");
```

I know will expect something like "`CMD>`" but unfortunately I didn't get an answer from the bluetooth modul. Baudrate is correct. Any further ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for me its "$$$" without carriage return
but I not sure that there is a firmware in RN4871 ?
Are you able to discover it with a PC or a smartphone ?
Regards